# extract from a list and apply a function of over the resulting tables in R

Tags: r, list, aggregate-functions

I am bootstrapping some data and got the output in a list format like below

```
              [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]           
 call         Expression Expression Expression Expression Expression 
 data.summary Numeric,27 Numeric,27 Numeric,27 Numeric,27 Numeric,27 
 corr.table   List,3     List,3     List,3     List,3     List,3    
 profile.test List,3     List,3     List,3     List,3     List,3
```

I want to extract the information in the *data.summary* part of the list which should look something like the two tables below, where each table is the output from a different bootstrapped sample.

```
              Group1      Group2      Group3
Variable1   -0.24318341   0.2438441   1.4045265
Variable2   -0.59632657   0.8538364   0.7574677
Variable3   -0.47474506   0.3928146   3.6156861
Variable4   -0.45918093   0.3757191   3.5414283
Variable5    0.22030575  -0.3028505  -0.4120158
Variable6   -0.43195698   0.3774980   3.0789076
Variable7    0.02884509  -0.0212604  -0.2470542
Variable8   -0.41558541   0.3564719   3.0327549
Variable9   -0.47583635   0.3943922   3.6169138

              Group1      Group2      Group3
Variable1   -0.24318341   0.2438441   1.4045265
Variable2   -0.59632657   0.8538364   0.7574677
Variable3   -0.47474506   0.3928146   3.6156861
Variable4   -0.45918093   0.3757191   3.5414283
Variable5    0.22030575  -0.3028505  -0.4120158
Variable6   -0.43195698   0.3774980   3.0789076
Variable7    0.02884509  -0.0212604  -0.2470542
Variable8   -0.41558541   0.3564719   3.0327549
Variable9   -0.47583635   0.3943922   3.6169138
```

My ultimate aim is to get the average across the bootstrapped samples into one table like below.

```
              Group1      Group2      Group3
Variable1   -0.24318341   0.2438441   1.4045265
Variable2   -0.59632657   0.8538364   0.7574677
Variable3   -0.47474506   0.3928146   3.6156861
Variable4   -0.45918093   0.3757191   3.5414283
Variable5    0.22030575  -0.3028505  -0.4120158
Variable6   -0.43195698   0.3774980   3.0789076
Variable7    0.02884509  -0.0212604  -0.2470542
Variable8   -0.41558541   0.3564719   3.0327549
Variable9   -0.47583635   0.3943922   3.6169138
```

Comment: Can you include the code required to get the same list output as you have to make this post reproducible?

Comment: what happens when you do `Reduce('+', output[2, ])/5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you could use `Reduce` divided by the length:

```
 Reduce('+', output[2, ]) / 5
```

Some data that can be reproduced. Think of the `coefficients` in the table below to correspond to the `data.summary` above

```
 output <- replicate(5,summary(lm(y~.,data.frame(y=rnorm(150),iris))))[-c(2:3,5:9),]
```